# Can GnuPG be configured to use the last *available* subkey?

Tags: configuration, gpg

For context, here's a representative sample of my keyring:

```
sec   rsa4096/MMMMMMMM 2018-01-01 [C] [expires: 2020-01-01]
uid         [ultimate] Fred Flintstone <fred@example.com>
ssb   rsa4096/AAAAAAAA 2018-01-01 [S] [expires: 2020-01-01]
ssb   rsa4096/BBBBBBBB 2018-01-01 [S] [expires: 2020-01-01]
```

I am using gpg version 2.1.11.

If I try to use my PGP key `MMMMMMMM` on a device which has the private key material for `BBBBBBBB`, everything works pretty much as I expect it to – gpg uses `BBBBBB` instead, since it's the last (signing) subkey.

However, whenever I try to use `MMMMMMMM` on a device which only has the private key material for `AAAAAAAA` (not `BBBBBBBB`), I get this error:

```
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
```

because gpg is trying to use the last subkey, `BBBBBBBB`. If I manually specify the exact subkey to use, e.g. by passing `-u AAAAAAAA!`, then it works, but I would rather not have to do so, since I share my config across several machines.

Is there a way to configure gpg to use the last subkey for which the private key material is available, rather than the absolute last subkey?

Comment: I'm thinking about opening a bug ticket on https://dev.gnupg.org/ - but I realized this:

For choice of encryption key does not really depend on if the secret part is available - as you often encrypt stuff for others, actually.
So the choice of which key to use is actually yours to make, not that of gpg

Comment: I did it in the end: https://dev.gnupg.org/T6381